# Выборка из двух таблиц по нескольким условиям

Tags: sql

есть запросы

```
SELECT (Name) FROM (table_lessons,table_rasp) WHERE (table_rasp.Lesson1 = 
table_lessons._id);

SELECT (Name) FROM table_lessons,table_rasp WHERE table_rasp.Lesson2 = 
table_lessons._id;

SELECT (Name) FROM table_lessons,table_rasp WHERE table_rasp.Lesson3 = 
table_lessons._id;
```

как я понял одним запросом этого сделать нельзя, их необходимо занести в ListView, вот не понимаю как это сделать.
Выборка должна быть в порядке, имен Lesson
Например, если использовать выбор, при помощи OR
То имея например в таблице `table_rasp: Lesson1=16, Lesson2=2, Lesson3 = 4`, то выбор, будет в порядке `2,4,16`, а надо `16,2,4`

Comment: `WHERE table_lessons._id IN (table_rasp.Lesson1, table_rasp.Lesson2, table_rasp.Lesson3)`

Comment: необходимо, чтобы выбирались в порядке Lesson-ов, а так будет выбор по возрастанию номера в таблице

Comment: Порядок задаётся предложением ORDER BY, а не условиями отбора в предложении WHERE. Например, `ORDER BY table_rasp.Lesson1 = 
table_lessons._id, table_rasp.Lesson2 = 
table_lessons._id`

Comment: И как же его задать? Возможен же вариант, с отсутствием какой-либо последовательности

Comment: Тогда UNION ALL плюс доп. поле идентификации поля извлечения, оно же признак сортировки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по обсуждению в комментариях, требуется

```
SELECT Name, 1 sorting_order 
    FROM table_lessons,table_rasp 
    WHERE table_rasp.Lesson1 = table_lessons._id
UNION ALL
SELECT Name, 2 
    FROM table_lessons,table_rasp 
    WHERE table_rasp.Lesson2 = table_lessons._id
UNION ALL
SELECT Name, 3 
    FROM table_lessons,table_rasp 
    WHERE table_rasp.Lesson3 = table_lessons._id
ORDER BY sorting_order /* , Name */ ;
```

Comment: а почему не `order by (case when table_rasp.Lesson1 = table_lessons._id then 1) `?

Comment: @norbornen *а почему не* Да потому что допускаю наличие дубликатов. И, судя по исходному коду, их надо выводить все.

Comment: чтобы дубли не слиплись, а стояли на своих местах. понял :)

Comment: aaaaaa, [он взял](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/832708/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B5-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) твой ответ и убрал самое интересное :)

Comment: @norbornen Ситуация, когда автор не умеет использовать данный ему ответ - не такая уж и редкая.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (Name) FROM (table_lessons,table_rasp) 
  WHERE 
    ((table_rasp.Lesson1 = table_lessons._id)
  or
    (table_rasp.Lesson2 = table_lessons._id)
  or
    (table_rasp.Lesson3 = table_lessons._id));
```

Comment: выборка будет произведена не в том порядке, в котором требуется

Comment: Добавьте сортировку по Name