# Ошибка в запросе или базе данных

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

Ошибка происходит в запросе

```
database.execSQL("SELECT (Name)" +
            "    FROM (table_lessons,table_rasp) " +
            "    WHERE (table_rasp.Lesson1 = table_lessons._id)" +
            " UNION ALL " +
            "SELECT (Name)" +
            "    FROM (table_lessons,table_rasp) " +
            "    WHERE (table_rasp.Lesson2 = table_lessons._id)" +
            " UNION ALL " +
            "SELECT (Name)" +
            "    FROM (table_lessons,table_rasp) " +
            "    WHERE (table_rasp.Lesson3 = table_lessons._id)" +
            " UNION ALL " +
            "SELECT (Name)" +
            "    FROM (table_lessons,table_rasp) " +
            "    WHERE (table_rasp.Lesson4 = table_lessons._id);");
```

Вот код DBHelper:

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private final Context fContext;
private final Activity fActivity;

public DBHelper(Context context, Activity fActivity){
    super (context, FieldsTable.DB_NAME, null, FieldsTable.DB_VERSION);
    fContext = context;
    this.fActivity = fActivity;
    onCreate(this.getWritableDatabase());
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+FieldsTable.DAYS_TABLE + " ("
            + FieldsTable.DAYS_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + FieldsTable.DAYS_NAME+" TEXT NOT NULL"
            +");");

    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+FieldsTable.GROUPS_TABLE + " ("
            + FieldsTable.GROUPS_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + FieldsTable.GROUPS_NAME+" TEXT NOT NULL"
            +");");

    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+FieldsTable.LESSONS_TABLE + " ("
            + FieldsTable.LESSONS_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + FieldsTable.LESSONS_NAME+" TEXT NOT NULL"
            +");");

    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "+FieldsTable.RASP_TABLE + " ("
            + FieldsTable.RASP_ID+" INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + FieldsTable.RASP_NAME_GROUP+" INTEGER NOT NULL, "
            +FieldsTable.RASP_NAME_DAY+" INTEGER NOT NULL, "
            +FieldsTable.RASP_NAME_LESSON1+ " INTEGER,"
            +FieldsTable.RASP_NAME_LESSON2+ " INTEGER,"
            +FieldsTable.RASP_NAME_LESSON3+ " INTEGER,"
            +FieldsTable.RASP_NAME_LESSON4+ " INTEGER"
            +");");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ FieldsTable.DAYS_TABLE);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ FieldsTable.GROUPS_TABLE);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ FieldsTable.LESSONS_TABLE);
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ FieldsTable.RASP_TABLE);
    onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
}

public void insertData(){
    //Stop stop = new Stop();
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();
    onUpgrade(database,FieldsTable.DB_VERSION,FieldsTable.DB_VERSION);
    database.execSQL(getLoadFile(this.fActivity,FieldsTable.DAYS_TABLE+".sql"));
    database.execSQL(getLoadFile(this.fActivity,FieldsTable.GROUPS_TABLE+".sql"));
    database.execSQL(getLoadFile(this.fActivity,FieldsTable.LESSONS_TABLE+".sql"));
    database.execSQL(getLoadFile(this.fActivity,FieldsTable.RASP_TABLE+".sql"));
    database.close();
}

public String getLoadFile(Activity activity,String FileName){
    byte[] buffer = null;
    InputStream is;
    try {
        is = activity.getAssets().open(FileName);
        int size = is.available();
        buffer = new byte[size];
        is.read(buffer );
        is.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    String str_data = new String(buffer, Charset.forName("cp1251"));
    return str_data;
}
```

}

Как можно видеть, таблицы связей между собой не имеют

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.programm.madness.lessontametable, PID: 22664
              java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.programm.madness.lessontametable/com.programm.madness.lessontametable.RaspActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error (code 0): Queries can be performed using SQLiteDatabase query or rawQuery methods only.
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
               Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: unknown error (code 0): Queries can be performed using SQLiteDatabase query or rawQuery methods only.
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForChangedRowCount(Native Method)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteConnection.java:738)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForChangedRowCount(SQLiteSession.java:754)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.executeUpdateDelete(SQLiteStatement.java:64)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1699)
                  at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1628)
                  at com.programm.madness.lessontametable.RaspActivity.onCreate(RaspActivity.java:27)
                  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
                  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
                  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Application terminated.

Comment: А что за ошибка? Скопируйте текст ошибки из лога в пост - вряд ли здесь есть экстрасенсы)

Comment: Ошибка в работе самой программы

Comment: он же пишет: "using SQLiteDatabase query or rawQuery methods only"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public void execSQL (String sql)
```

Execute a single SQL statement that is NOT a SELECT or any other SQL statement that returns data.

Не используется с запросами, возвращающими данные.

А так да: "Queries can be performed using SQLiteDatabase ***query or rawQuery methods*** only."

Answer (score 1):

Я понял ошибку, достаточно было просто использовать другой метод

```
String query = "SELECT (Name)" +
            "    FROM (table_lessons,table_rasp) " +
            "    WHERE (table_rasp.Lesson1 = table_lessons._id)" +
            " UNION ALL " +
            "SELECT (Name)" +
            "    FROM (table_lessons,table_rasp) " +
            "    WHERE (table_rasp.Lesson2 = table_lessons._id)" +
            " UNION ALL " +
            "SELECT (Name)" +
            "    FROM (table_lessons,table_rasp) " +
            "    WHERE (table_rasp.Lesson3 = table_lessons._id)" +
            " UNION ALL " +
            "SELECT (Name)" +
            "    FROM (table_lessons,table_rasp) " +
            "    WHERE (table_rasp.Lesson4 = table_lessons._id);";
    Cursor cursorRasp = database.rawQuery(query,null);
```